# How to Go Back to an Original Prompt in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a basic calculator that takes the first number, takes the operation(+,-,*,/), and second number.  If a person puts in a zero for the first number and/or the second number my program is supposed to go back to the number it was at and ask again for a number other than 0.  So if a person puts in 0 for number 2 then my program will take the person back to number two.  I am also supposed to do the same concept for the operation but have the person start over if they do not put in the operation available to use which includes the ones previously shown in parentheses.  Below is the code I have so far.  Any help would be appreciated.  My class is currently on while loops and breaks among other things, but I am wondering if those two would be beneficial in my code.

```
#Programming Fundamentals Assignment Unit 5
#Create a basic calculator function

while True:
#Num1 will require user input  
    num1 = input ("Enter the first number\n")

#Operation will require user input  
    operation = raw_input("Enter the operation(+,-,*,/)\n")

#Num2 will require user input    
    num2 = input("Enter the second number\n")

#Now to define how the operation will be used
    if operation == "+":
        print num1+num2
    elif operation == "-":
        print num1-num2
    elif operation == "*":
        print num1*num2
    elif operation == "/":
        print num1/num2
    else:
        print "Please enter an operation"

#Exit will end the calculation from going into a loop    
exit()
```

Comment: Do you want the calculator to run forever...?  Because, if you don't that's where you use a `break`.

Comment: I don't.  I used break but it would always go back to the first number prompt which I think is because I had the while statement being used for num1, operation, and num2.  I did try giving a while statement to all three, but had issues again with the program skipping to the operation step without addressing 0 being entered when it should require the user to enter another number.

Comment: Yes, a judicious use of `break` will get you what you want... say if you ever type "`quit`" as input, then the while loop would execute the `break`.

Answer (score 1):

Put loops around your various inputs to ensure proper checking. So for the first number, you could have:

```
num1 = 0
while num1 == 0:
    num1 = input ("Enter the first number\n")
```

This'll keep asking till they input something that isn't a 0.

For the second issue (starting over if they enter an invalid operation), you want to immediately check if the operation is valid and if it isn't, then you need to re-loop (which is just by skipping the remaining parts of the current loop).

So to easily check if it's valid:

```
operation not in ["+","-","*","/"]
```

which will return false if they enter invalid, and then the second part (skipping the rest of the loop) can easily be accomplished with the "continue" keyword.

```
if operation not in ["+","-","*","/"]:
    continue
```

This will take you back to the beginning of the loop, asking for new number first number.

When you want to stop execution, you'll need to implement "break" which will break out of the inner most loop that it's a part of.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  My program now works exactly as I wanted it too.